# "There is no boxing conversion" error with generic type in Microsoft.Data.Analysis package

Tags: c#, .net, dataframe

I am trying to use C# DataFrames like in the tutorial [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/):

```
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int> colPositions = new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Positions");
```

I am getting this error:

```
error CS0315: The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<T>'. There is no boxing conversion from 'int' to '?'.
```

However, it should work, and does work in the interactive Jupyter notebook version on the blog post above.

The `PrimitiveDataFrameColumn` is defined as follows:

```
public class PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<[IsUnmanagedAttribute]
T> : DataFrameColumn, IEnumerable<T?>, IEnumerable where T : struct, object
```

What exactly is the problem here? As I understand it, the generic type must be a non-nullable value type, which int, float and simple structs should all be.

Answer (score 0):

Chenge this

```
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int> colPositions = new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Positions");
```

into this:

```
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int> colPositions = new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn("Positions");
```

Cheers.

Comment: It does not seem to answer the question at all if you just tell OP to change the code.

Comment: Feel free to add more @E.Zacarias, that's the beauty of a community - anyone can add a little piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I can't, because I myself was trying to find an answer similar to the question. But probably it is better for me to create a new question when I have time enough to put it into words and examples. My issue is not exactly 1:1 with this, and just with the code here I am unable to tell why it should work just by removing the `<int>` part.